# Microsoft Teams Bot file card info is corrupted by sending a file info to a channel

Tags: c#, botframework, microsoft-teams

I'am using the Microsoft Bot Framework to send a file card to a channel or user,
but it looks like the file card has not the correct format... It is not possible to click on the filecard or open the file...

[image]

How I generate the card:

```
FileInfoCard card = new FileInfoCard()
    {
        FileType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document",
        UniqueId = driveItemUniqueId,
    };

    Attachment att = card.ToAttachment();
    att.ContentUrl = fileLocation;
    att.Name = fileName;


    replyToConversation.Attachments.Add(att);
    return replyToConversation;
```

And the json code which will be send to teams is the following:

```
[{
"contentType": "application/vnd.microsoft.teams.card.file.info",
"contentUrl": "https://fileLocation.com/xyz",
"content": {
    "uniqueId": "jfölasjflasjföiu289u9o2or2jor2l1ö1l3jrlö12j4l",
    "fileType": "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document",
    "etag": null
},
"name": "Meeting Minutes - testmeeting 2 fso - 26-1-2019.docx",
"thumbnailUrl": null
```

}]

The Microsoft ressource to this topic:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/bots/bots-files

with the following example:

```
    {
  "attachments": [{
    "contentType": "application/vnd.microsoft.teams.card.file.info",
    "contentUrl": "https://contoso.sharepoint.com/personal/johnadams_contoso_com/Documents/Applications/file_example.txt",
    "name": "file_example.txt",
    "content": {
      "uniqueId": "1150D938-8870-4044-9F2C-5BBDEBA70C8C",
      "fileType": "txt",
    }
  }]
}
```

EDIT: Additional information.
I'm not sure if the uniqueId is correct. The word file is uploaded to a SharePoint site. This UniqueId looks not like the unique GUID in the example... on the Team iOS App I can click on the link but there will be a message that it is not possible to access this file.

EDIT: Unique ID fixed but the problem still occurs on MS Teams Desktop client.
I have replaced the unique id with the GUID in the Ctag from the file which I get from the Graph API. On the iOs App it's working now but on the desktop client, there is still the red triangle.

Button on Iphone:
[image]

Comment: We have tried same code and it worked for us. Please check your manifest version and under bot section need to add supportfiles :true. Please update this value and try again.

Comment: @Arun-MSFT supportfiles:true is part of our manifest file. We also uploading images to this bot and this is working as expected. I'm not sure if the uniqueId is correct. The word file is uploaded to a SharePoint site. This UniqueId looks not like the unique GUID in the example... on the Team iOs App i cann click on the link but there will be a message that it is not possible to access this file.

Comment: @Arun-MSFT I have replaced the unique id with the GUID in the Ctag from the file which i get from the Graph API. On the iOs App its working now but on the desktop client there is still the red triangle.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please set the FileType to *docx* instead as given below:

```
        FileInfoCard card = new FileInfoCard()
        {
            FileType = "docx",
            UniqueId = Guid.NewGuid().ToString() // unique id.
        };

        Attachment att = card.ToAttachment();
        att.ContentUrl = contentUrl;
        att.Name = name;
```